# Milliseconds in java/android before 1970?

Tags: java, android, milliseconds

I know how to get the milliseconds for a date after 1.1.1970. But how can I get the milliseconds for a specific date that occurs *before* that date?
I need that in an android app.
Thanks!

Comment: If you're using specific dates, using ms since an arbitrary epoch probably isn't the best idea. Why not just use a Date library?

Comment: I don't know how you're getting the milliseconds after the date, but most libraries should work fine with negative millis-since-epoch. -86400000 represents 24 hours before epoch, for instance.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: whatever you tried put it in the question please, there's an edit button

Comment: @lelloman No problem anymore. I don't know that went wrong, but now it works, also with the negative number. Thanks again for all the good answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All numbers are signed in java, so all numbers can be negative. Therefore you can have a date with a negative amount of milliseconds. Therfore dates with a timestamp which is less than 0 is definitely possible.

You can know the earliest possible date by performing:

```
new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)
```

You'll find that this returns a date which is more than 292 million years ago. This is even before the jurassic era. So there really isn't a need to worry about dates before 1970 :)

Comment: The `Date` class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes in general and the `java.time.Instant` class in particular. See [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) for an adaptation for Android of a back-port for Java 6 & 7.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. The calculation with the negative numbers work well now. Don't know, why it didn't before...

Answer (score 1):

Using java.time.Instant, get your date in the Instant and you can use the getEpochSecond() method to return the number of seconds before the Epoch and just convert from that.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html  for more details about the Instant class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but in Android, there is no Instant, except the incomplete ThreeTenABP.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 1953 , 1 , 17 )
         .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .toInstant()
         .toEpochMilli()
```

…yields a negative number:

> -535057200000

## Details

As the other Answers said:

(a) In representing moments as a count-from-[epoch-reference-date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)), moments before the epoch use negative numbers, moments after the epoch use positive numbers.

(b) You should be using java.time classes rather than the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy. See below for info on back-port to Android.

## Using java.time

Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for a date-only value, with no time-of-day nor time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1953 , 1 , 17 );
```

To convert to a moment, let's get the first moment of the day on that date. That means specifying a time zone, as the date varies around the globe by time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z );
```

Extract an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

From the `Instant`, extract the number of milliseconds since the epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`). Beware of data-loss, as the java.time classes can hold a moment with a resolution of up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond); asking for [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) means lopping off any nanoseconds if present.

```
long epochMillis = instant.toEpochMilli();
```

See this [code run line in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/H0bLnC).

> ld.toString(): 1953-01-17
>
> zdt.toString(): 1953-01-17T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> instant.toString(): 1953-01-17T05:00:00Z
>
> epochMillis: -535057200000

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: The class `java.util.Date` might be legacy for you but not for Google who still considers this old API as standard on Android. There are good reasons to regret this decision of Google but we have at least to respect it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Basil Bourque. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was something I cannot reproduce.  Before 1.1.1970 the values are negative. Now, my program calculates right, but I think, I didn't change something in the code. Maybe it was a cached version, which caused the problems. Thanks for all answers!